# Clearance from a bath external vent to a kitchen external vent?

Tags: code-compliance, exhaust-fan, california

I know that bath and kitchen vents have to terminate outside a building, at least 3' from the operable portion of a window.

What if I have two such vents?  Can they come out next to *each other?*

Here for code I'm under the California CMC and CRC (based on the IAPMO UMC).